# How to make Highcharts scrollbar always Visible?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I need to implement an scrollable column chart with Highcharts.

> **Question:** How do I make the scrollbar always visible? Its visible when I try to scroll and hides back when not in use.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
chart: {
    type: 'column',
    scrollablePlotArea: {
            enabled: true,
        minWidth: 1800
    },
    marginRight: 30
},
scrollbar: {
    enabled:true
    },
title: {
    text: 'Stacked column chart'
},
xAxis: {
    categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas'],
    scrollbar: {
        enabled: true
    },
},
yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    title: {
        text: 'Total fruit consumption'
    },
    stackLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        style: {
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            color: ( // theme
                Highcharts.defaultOptions.title.style &&
                Highcharts.defaultOptions.title.style.color
            ) || 'gray',
            textOutline: 'none'
        }
    }
},
legend: {
    align: 'right',
    x: -30,
    verticalAlign: 'top',
    y: 25,
    floating: true,
    backgroundColor:
        Highcharts.defaultOptions.legend.backgroundColor || 'white',
    borderColor: '#CCC',
    borderWidth: 1,
    shadow: false
},
tooltip: {
    headerFormat: '<b>{point.x}</b><br/>',
    pointFormat: '{series.name}: {point.y}<br/>Total: {point.stackTotal}'
},
plotOptions: {
    column: {
        stacking: 'normal',
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true
        }
    }
},
series: [{
    name: 'John',
    data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
}, {
    name: 'Jane',
    data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1]
}, {
    name: 'Joe',
    data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]
}]
});
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/5zkye8f7/9/

Comment: Hi, what is your environment? On my iOS, in firefox, chrome and safari the scrollbar is visible all the time.

Comment: for me its not visible when a mover my mouse out of area. all browswers...

Comment: Now I also have the same when using a touchpad. The scrollbar is displayed at all times when the mouse is plugged in. I need to test this.

Comment: This depends on the browser's native scrollbar settings, so you cannot set the visibility of scrollablePlotArea through the library's API settings.

Comment: okay note, thanks for checking.